# How to get all values in a row on clicking on particular row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I need to get all values present in a row on clicking anywhere in a row  and also get hidden variables from

```
$("tr.podTableRow  td:not(.pdficon)").click(function() {
  var tableData = $(this).closest('tr').children('td').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();

  var podActualDeliveryDate = $.trim(tableData[0]);
  var podOrderNo = $.trim(tableData[1]);
  var podDeliveryNo = $.trim(tableData[2]);
  var podfileName = $("#fileNameDelete", this).val();
  var podFilePath = $(this).find("td.pdficon a").attr("href");)};
```

Here Im not able to get the value for `podfileName` & `podFilePath`.

```
<tr class="podTableRow">
  <td>
    <a href="#tandcLightbox1" class="open-inline-popup-link confirmpopup1"style="display: none;"></a>
    ${podfiles.actualDeliveryDate}
  </td>                                                         
  <td class="pdficon">
    <a href="${podfiles.path}" target="_blank">
      <img src="/etc/designs/nextgen/shell/images/pdf.png" style="width: 20px;">
    </a>
  </td>
  <td class="pdficon">
    <a href="#delete-pod-lightbox" class="open-inline-popup-link confirmpopupPOD" style="display: none;"></a>
    <a href="#" class="icon-alone delete deleteicon"> 
      <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-close"></span> 
      <span class="visuallyHidden">Close</span> 
      <input type="hidden" value="${podfiles.delcoCode}" id="delcoCodeDelete" name="delcoCodeDelete" /> 
      <input type="hidden" value="${podfiles.fileName}" id="fileNameDelete" name="fileNameDelete" />
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: dont know if it is the problem but you have an error in your script at the last part. the `;)};` it should be `;});`

Comment: Just FYI your HTML is invalid as you cannot put `input` elements inside an `a`

Comment: with this code, im able to get the values,
$("#testTableSearchBy tr .deleteicon").on('click',function(){

     var  pdfFileNameDel=$("#fileNameDelete", this).val(); 
 $("#fileNameDelete1").val(pdfFileNameDel);
 var  delcoCodeNameDel=$("#delcoCodeDelete", this).val();
 $("#delcoCodeDelete1").val(delcoCodeNameDel); 


});

Answer (score 0):

Be careful on your html code : it's invalid.
For your question : 
HTML :

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="podTableRow">
      <td>
        <a href="#tandcLightbox1" class="open-inline-popup-link confirmpopup1" style="display: none;"></a>my date1
      </td>
      <td class="pdficon">
        <a href="mypath1" target="_blank">
          <img src="/etc/designs/nextgen/shell/images/pdf.png" style="width: 20px;">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="pdficon">
        <a href="#delete-pod-lightbox" class="open-inline-popup-link confirmpopupPOD" style="display: none;"></a>
        <a href="#" class="icon-alone delete deleteicon"> </a>
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-close"></span>
        <span class="visuallyHidden">Close</span>
        <input type="hidden" value="delname1" id="delcoCodeDelete" name="delcoCodeDelete" />
        <input type="hidden" value="filename1" id="fileNameDelete" name="fileNameDelete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="podTableRow">
      <td>
        <a href="#tandcLightbox1" class="open-inline-popup-link confirmpopup1" style="display: none;"></a>mydate2
      </td>
      <td class="pdficon">
        <a href="mypath2" target="_blank">
          <img src="/etc/designs/nextgen/shell/images/pdf.png" style="width: 20px;">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="pdficon">
        <a href="#delete-pod-lightbox" class="open-inline-popup-link confirmpopupPOD" style="display: none;"></a>
        <a href="#" class="icon-alone delete deleteicon"> </a>
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-close"></span>
        <span class="visuallyHidden">Close</span>
        <input type="hidden" value="delname2" id="delcoCodeDelete" name="delcoCodeDelete" />
        <input type="hidden" value="filname2" id="fileNameDelete" name="fileNameDelete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS :

```
$(".podTableRow").click(function() {
  alert($(this).children('td:first').text());
  alert($(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').children("a").attr('href'));
  alert($(this).children('td:nth-child(3)').children('input[name="delcoCodeDelete"]').val());
  alert($(this).children('td:nth-child(3)').children('input[name="fileNameDelete"]').val());
});
```

You can test it on this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/HRoux/s0uk8e76/

To conclude, you can play with .children() to take whatever that you want.